# my Div doesn't break lines automatically when writing one big word

Tags: css, yui, richtext

I'm using a YUI rich text editor in my project. it works fine for me, but I'm facing an issue. It doesn't break lines automatically when writing one big word as shown in the image.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the CSS 3 property [`word-wrap`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-css3-text-20110412/#word-wrap):

```
div {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Supported by IE 5.5+, Firefox 3.5+, Chrome 1.0+, Opera 10.5+, Safari 1.0+.

Alternatively, you can wrap everything in a `<wbr>` tag, although it's not supported by Opera.

Answer (score 1):

@ali; just write

```
div{
word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

`word-wrap` force the text to wrap.

check this for more http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/word-wrap-force-text-to-wrap